# Iron-router with in a static context

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've the following page:

main.html

```
<html>
<body>
   <div>
      [more static content]
      <div id="content"></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

tpl1.html

```
<template name="something">
   [...]
</template>
```

And I want to use Iron-router to fill the "something" template into the "content" div. I cannot find a way to route a path to render only a div. I tried to do something like:

```
<div id="content">{{yield}}</div>
```

but always the result is:

```
<html>
<body>
   <div>
      [more static content]
      <div id="content"></div>
   </div>
   [... content from "something" template ...]
</body>
</html>
```

And not:

```
<html>
<body>
   <div>
      [more static content]
      <div id="content">[... content from "something" template ...]</div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

what is what I want to do.

My iron-router config is:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('principal',{
        path:"/someaction",
        template:"something"
    });
```

¿How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try *something like* `<div id="content">{{yield}}</div>`, or exactly that? That's how it should be done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have it. The only additional code you *should* need is adding a `{{yield}}` into your div:

```
<html>
<body>
   <div>
      [more static content]
      <div id="content">{{yield}}</div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you just read down the [iron-router github](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) a bit you should quickly find a great section talking about [yield](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#using-a-layout-with-yields). You can even use multiple ones.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, putting the main.html text into a template:

```
<template name="main">
   <html>
   <body>
     <div>
         [more static content]
         <div id="content">{{yield}}</div>
      </div>
   </body>
   </html>
</template>
```

and in the router:

```
 this.route('principal',{
    path:"/someaction",
    template:"something",
    layoutTemplate:"main"
 });
```

This isn't what I want (because now the accounts-ui doesn't work), but it's something :P.

If someone knows how to do the original task, it will be excelent!